# Converting encoded chars back to original character - PHP

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

My Database returns this following JSON with special chars. I need to convert it back to original chars:

```
{   "event_id":"5153",
      "name":"Event Test",
      "description":"Pers&ouml;nlichkeit Universit&auml;t&quot;",
      "start_time":"2013-04-24 9:00 AM EST",
        "end_time":"2013-04-24 5:00 PM EST"  
}
```

I want to strip out all HTML chars. And convert all chars like `&ouml` to original chars. So the `description` in the above JSON should actually look like this

> Persönlichkeit Universität"

I am doing `array_walk` on the array before encoding array to JSON, and `strip_tags` on each element. 
This is fine. (That resulted in the above JSON.).

To get the chars back, I tried:

```
  1. encoding again with utf8_encode
  2. htmlspecialchars_decode
  3. html_entity_decode  //This one is eliminating the character altogether.
```

But nothing gave the original char back.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I tried this. But now the description field returns as null

```
    array_walk_recursive($results, function (&$val) {
    $val = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($val));
});

$results = json_encode( $results);
```

Comment: What about using html_entity_decode BEFORE json_encoding it?

Comment: Before and after json_encode, I see the same results. So I am not sure how calling html_entity_decode before json_encode helps?

Answer (score 2):

I came to this topic while looking for something. After 3 years, the question still unanswered.

json_encode accepts options as second parameter. If you use it as below, the special characters will shown as original.

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`html_entity_decode` should do the trick. I think your problem is somewhere else. Remember that `json_encode` only accepts UTF-8 characters. So you maybe have to `utf8_encode` your string.

Comment: Please try to add a call to utf8_encode around that call to strip_tags.

Comment: I tried it. No use. It shows: `Pers&ouml;nlichkeit Universit&auml;t"`